# NHibernate child object's ID problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I retrieve a Parent-object, the Child-object's ID is not always predictable. For example, sometimes it is set with 0 (zero), sometimes the actual value and sometimes -1.

Why?

How can I solve this problem?

For code and mapping-files plz see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211552/nhibernate-data-retrieve-problem) older question from me.

Comment: Can you provide a code example?  It really depends on how you are loading the child entities (lazy vs. eager) and what the ID fields are mapped to.

Comment: Load some code so we can help you out...

Comment: For code and mapping-files plz see provided link in the update.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that SQL Server's default identity setting will *never* set a value of 0 or -1 something is fishy.

Also, since the TeacherDetail is actually a supplementary/sibbling entity of Teacher why the additional ID for TeacherDetail? You can map a Primary Foreign Key in nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

Your Teacher and TeacherDetail are setup different.

One is a many-to-one and the other is a one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your premise is incorrect.

A single teacher only has a single detail, and therefore nothing is many-to-one.  It's all just a property, as in a teacher has a property of TeacherDetail.

Either way, there is no way that TeacherDetailsMapping has a many-to-one...two teachers will never share the same details.

Fix the improper mapping and your issue, a result of bad mapping, will disappear.

Comment: I don't know whether you are aware or not, one-to-one relationship from the patent side is mapped as many-to-one with unique set to true. See this: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loaded-one-to-one-with-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: perhaps being clear about what you are trying to do would be helpful.  That is a workaround 'trick' not a standard practice.
Not sure what to tell you, I'm pretty sure you can map it "better".

Comment: @Mirage this IS the way to map one-to-ones; one side maps as a many-to-one